# I need to export my data frame with colour conditional formatting on specific rows in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have a dataframe, df1 which is data manipulated from an imported excel, and I need to export it back out to have specific formatting that the original file had - it has many columns, but essentially if the 'Subproject' column has NA1 in it, that whole row should be Yellow (#FFFF00).

If 'Subporject' column has a code starting SE followed by any number (i.e. could be SE235, or SE062) the whole row should be red (#FF0000).

Also, if in the Sample_Thaws column there is any number other than 0 (i.e. 1 to 10), and the code in the 'Subproject' column starts with RE and not SE, the whole row should be blue (#0099FF).

I can export df1 without the formatting, but don't know how to put it in, ive been trying to use openxlsx library.

Or if possible, is there a way when reading in the excel to read the row colours and give an annotation column of the row colours such that i could use excels conditional formatting after export to put the colours back in.

The code below is what I've been trying to do, but when I use the saveWorkbook(), no file is created and I'm unsure why. I also didn't add an argument for the fact that rows in blue need the Subproject code to start with RE.  Sorry this is a bit long!

```
# #read in the original data
> df1 <- read.xlsx("1946_P2_master.xlsx")  
# #(I then did the data manipulation and assigned the dataframe back to df1)

# Create a workbook
>   wb <- createWorkbook()

# #we need colors such that SE in Subproject column gives a red colour, or NA1 in the same column gives yellow, and  any number but 0 in samplethaws gives blue,
> yellow_rows <- which(df1$Subproject == "NA1")
> red_rows <- which(grepl("^SE\\d+", df1$Subproject))
> blue_rows <- which(df1$Sample_Thaws != 0)

# Add a worksheet
> addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet1")

# Write data to the worksheet
> writeData(wb, "Sheet1", df1)

# Create styles for yellow, red, and blue
> yellow_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "#FFFF00")
>     red_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "#FF0000")
>     blue_style <- createStyle(fgFill = "#0099FF")

# Apply styles to the respective rows
> styles_and_rows <- list(
>       list(style = yellow_style, rows = yellow_rows),
>       list(style = red_style, rows = red_rows),
>       list(style = blue_style, rows = blue_rows)
>     )

# Loop through the list of styles and rows
>  for (style_row_pair in styles_and_rows) {
>       style <- style_row_pair$style
>       rows <- style_row_pair$rows

# Check if rows are not empty, Apply style to each row
> if (length(rows) > 0) {
>         for (row in rows) {
>           addStyle(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", style = style, rows = row + 1, cols = 1:ncol(df1))
>         }
>       }
>     }

# Write the dataframe with applied styles to an Excel file
>  saveWorkbook(wb, "formatted_data.xlsx")
```

dput(head(df1)) returns the following (example data):

````
"3330_534-20210403 RE278.2 2 of 15", "3330_534-20210403 RE278.2 3 of 15", 
"3330_534-20210403 RE278.2 4 of 15"), Sample_Project_Code = c("3330_", 
"3330_", "3330_", "3330_", "3330_"), Sample_Original_ID = c("534-20210403", 
"534-20210403", "534-20210403", "534-20210403", "534-20210403"
), Sample_Part = c(NA, "1 of 15", "2 of 15", "3 of 15", "4 of 15"
), Original_Batch_Code = c("RE277.4", "RE278.2", "RE278.2", "RE278.2", 
"RE278.2"), Subproject = c("RE277.4", "RE278.2", "RE278.2", "RE278.2", 
"RE278.2"), LastAction = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), Date_Of_Import = structure(c(18720, 18720, 18720, 
18720, 18720), class = "Date"), ItemType = c("A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), Sample_Container_Type = c("card", "2ml tube ", "2ml tube ", 
"2ml tube ", "2ml tube "), Sample_Thaws = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Age = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Subject_Sex = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M"), named_person = c("Kay", "Kay", "Kay", "Kay", 
"Kay"), Researcher = c("Bee", "Bee", "Bee", "Bee", "Bee"), Technician = c("Jay", 
"Jay", "Jay", "Jay", "Jay"), Identifier = c("ACR", "ACR", "ACR", 
"ACR", "ACR"), PPL_Sender = c("Bee", "Bee", "Bee", "Bee", "Bee"
), Extraction_Date = structure(c(18720, 18720, 18720, 18720, 
18720), class = "Date"), Sample_PLPI = c(340, 65, 65, 65, 65), 
    Date_Sent = structure(c(18720, 18720, 18720, 18720, 18720
    ), class = "Date"), Date_Received = structure(c(18720, 18720, 
    18720, 18720, 18720), class = "Date"), D = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Ethics_Code = c("33/333/3", 
    "33/333/4", "33/333/5", "33/333/6", "33/333/7"), Sample_Volume = c(NA, 
    500, 500, 500, 500), Method = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Comments = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Row = c(20, 34, 34, 35, 35), Col = c("A", 
    "K", "L", "A", "B"), Level5Name = c("Book 18", "Shelf 14", 
    "Shelf 14", "Shelf 14", "Shelf 14"), Level4Name = c("Compartment B", 
    "Compartment E", "Compartment E", "Compartment E", "Compartment E"
    ), Level3Name = c("Freezer 8", "Freezer 7", "Freezer 7", 
    "Freezer 7", "Freezer 7"), Level2Name = c("Ground Floor", 
    "Ground Floor", "Ground Floor", "Ground Floor", "Ground Floor"
    ), Level1Name = c("AH", "AH", "AH", "AH", "AH")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")```
````

Comment: could you share the results of `dput(head(df1))`, if its not sensitive data?

Comment: Welcome to the site! A few notes: (1) You're making the code formatting harder than it needs to be. Put three backticks on a line, then put all your code, then put three backticks on a line. (2) Please save the RStudio tag for problems specific to the RStudio code editor - like if you have code that runs okay on the command line but has an issue in RStudio. (3) It's always helpful if you can share some sample data. `dput()` is the easiest way to share sample data, `dput(head(df1))` as stefan requests, will make copy/pasteable R code to reproduce the first 6 lines of your `df1`.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused by the formatting - I can't really share the top of the data as it includes sensitive info unfortunately :(

Comment: Proprietary data is a normal thing on SO, and it makes a lot of sense that you cannot share it. However ... that doesn't mean we need to work in a vacuum. It's your responsibility to make your question as reproducible as possible and as necessary, and in this case it would really help. Your question doesn't need to have "real" data in it, just "representative" data. You can use public datasets (e.g., `mtcars`, `iris`, `dplyr::starwars`, and `ggplot2::diamonds` are popular sample datasets), or you can come up with your own, whether random (pls use `set.seed`) or deterministic `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: Hi all, Thanks! I've made up the data, but the strucutre / column headers are the same as my real data set